# Converting from Behrmann CRS map to +proj=longlat WGS84 in R

Tags: r, wgs84

I have a shapefile of grid cells of 200km x 200km covering land areas of the world in Behrmann Equal Area Cylindrical projection. My goal is to convert the shapefile to +proj=longlat WGS84 format so I can match it to maps in commonly used projections such as wrld_simpl in maptools. However, I have not been successful and would appreciate some help with this.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(RCurl)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
data("wrld_simpl")

tmp <- tempfile() download.file("https://github.com/darunabas/extras/blob/master/temp_shapefile.zip?raw=true", destfile = tmp)
unzip(tmp, exdir = ".")

s <- rgdal::readOGR("temp_shapefile")
proj4string(s) = CRS("+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

p <- spTransform(s, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

I got the following error:
non finite transformation detected:
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
    failure in Polygons 1106 Polygon 1 points 
In addition: Warning message:
In .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
  2 projected point(s) not finite

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in the geo-worls, but this might help:

```
library( sf )
sf <- read_sf( "./temp_shapefile.shp")
st_crs( sf ) <- "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
sf2 <- st_transform( sf, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Wimpel. Although it didn't return any error, the resulting plot looks very weird with a long line stretching below the equator and many grid cells are missing in the projected map.